# How can i press keyboard keys with selenium without physical keyboard

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to create automation with selenium that will install chrome extension.
I'm having a problem when i try to run this jar on amazon virtual machine,
because when i try to press enter with robot class it doesn't work because i don't have physical keyboard attached.
I can't use sendkeys within the selenium because the pop from google is not at the same page and selenium can't recognize it.
any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can use "sikuli" which is basically uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. You can find it [here](http://www.sikuli.org/)

**Steps would be :**

1. Download sikuli java jar
2. Add this jar to your build path
3. Crop the pop up you want to click
4. Write desired sikuli code for that.

Please let me know if it can help You. If you wish to add sikuli in your project. I can help you for that very basic sikuli script.

Comment: This sikuli doesn't need input of keyboard like robot?

Comment: sikuli is using robot class... so it wont work on vm with no keyboard and mouse... is there any other solution?

Comment: No you dont need any input from keyboard. You just need to crop the image of desired element.

Comment: This is a quote from sikuli site:
-- Real Screen needed

The system running SikuliX scripts or any apps using SikuliX features must have a real screen connected. So called headless systems are not supported (Java restriction). While using SikuliX features, the screen should not be in sleep mode nor show a screen saver. It must be in a state, that a user could work with the system and watch on the screen what is going on.

-- Using Virtual Machines

Running it in VM guest systems as the above mentioned should usually work, but might have quirks.

so i don't have any screen...

Comment: @Pikolo   Then it will be difficult for you to work with running keyboard commands without having physical keyboard connected. Please keep this thread open so that any other solution mat come.

Comment: yea, I'm still searching for a solution.